# Changing the picture in a pictureBox with a variable

Tags: c#, .net

This is my code to load a picture box with an image and it works fine.

```
picBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.imageName;
```

I would like to replace "imageName" with a variable like String x = "imageName" and change the code to something like this.

```
picBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.x;
```

It does not seem to work.  Is there some other way to do it, and why does this not work?  Thank you.  Also, noob alert.  I did google the question and look around for a solution before asking on these forums.

Comment: You can't bind it this way. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: What type of you project? WPF, WinForms, UWP?

Comment: Windows Form Project.  I want to be able to change the picture in a picture box at run time.  I don't want to make this question to complicated but I want to have an object property that controls the picturebox.  So if you were to change the object it would also change the picture in the picture box.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Try  
string x="image1";
picBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(x);

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type string to 'System.Drawing.Image' , is the error I get with that code.  So I need to convert the datatype somehow?

Comment: Upps. VS is right) you need to get object Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(x); 
and may be cast it to image 
(System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(x);

Comment: That did it sur.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Resources;

...

ResourceManager resManager = new ResourceManager("YourRootNamespace.YourResourceFileName", GetType().Assembly);
Image myImage = (Image)(resManager.GetObject("ImageNameInResourceFile"));
picBox1.Image = myImage;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// given that x is a string variable referring to a resource name
// you can do the following
picBox1.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(x);
```